# Can a unity script simply be a public variable

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, methods

I was trying to add a script that attaches a global damage rating to the object however the script came up with a console error,

> error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static 
>       field, method, or property `AttackStat.atk`

So I am confused, is there a requirement for a unity script that I am not meeting or something, I am quite new to programming in unity

Thanks for your time

Attackstat.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackStat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float atk;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

As the error message stated, `atk` is an instance member of the class `AttackStat` you need to create an instance/object of the class to access them.

For example :

```
AttackStat attackStatInstance = new AttackStat();
float  vlueObject = attackStatInstance.atk // It is accessible now
```

**Solution 2:**

If you really want to use `atk` without creating the instance(say `AttackStat.atk`) then the variable should be defined as static, that means the definition will be like the following:

```
public class AttackStat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float atk;
}
```

Comment: Note that you cannot call `new` on MonoBehaviour derived objects. You must use `AddComponent<T>()`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES, check [Static Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

```
public class AttackStat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float atk;
}
```

Comment: I tried this the only thing is it is not giving me a space to add a value to the object which is what I was hoping. Like having a public float variable in a normal script

Comment: Static would mean that all objects that use this value would share the value. This is almost certainly not desired. If it is, then the class no longer needs to extend MonoBehaviour and can also be a `static class`